# Children route doesn't render reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have this PrivateRoutes.js file that checks if the user is authenticated or not and renders either a 404 not found page or the profile:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoutes = ({ children }) =>{

const [isloggedin, setLoggedin] = useState()

const isUserAuth = async() =>{
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/isUSerAuth',{
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token") },   
      });
      const data = await response.json()
      console.log(data.auth)
      if(data.auth === true){
        setLoggedin(true)
      }else{
        setLoggedin(false)
      }
      console.log(isloggedin)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
    }
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
      isUserAuth()
  })

return (

    isloggedin ? children : <Navigate to ="/404" />

);


}

export default PrivateRoutes
```

So ofc when I console.log(data.auth) I recieve true but when I console.log(isloggedin) after the if statement it says undefined and it doesn't take me to the children route(profile) which I nested like this in the App.js it takes me to the 404 page:

```
   <Route path='/profile' element={
           <PrivateRoutes>
           <Profile />
         </PrivateRoutes>
      } />
```

so idk why isloggedin not taking the value of true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `isUserAuth` function is async, so the component will be rendered with `isLoggedin` as `false` *before* it changes to `true`. Instead of rendering a 404 page, you are [redirecting to another location](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/navigate#navigate) with `<Navigate to="/404" />`.

You could add a loader that first is rendered, so that the `<Navigate>` will not be called until `isLoggedin` is set to the correct state:

```js
isLoading
  ? <Loader />
  : isloggedin 
    ? children 
    : <Navigate to ="/404" />
```

UPDATE: I've updated your code with a solution:

```js
const [isloggedin, setLoggedin] = useState(false);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

const isUserAuth = async() =>{
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/isUSerAuth',{
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token") },   
      });
      const data = await response.json()
      console.log(data.auth)
      if(data.auth === true){
        setLoggedin(true)
      }else{
        setLoggedin(false)
      }
      console.log(isloggedin)
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
    }
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
      isUserAuth()
  })

return (
    isLoading
      ? <p>Loading...</p>
      : isloggedin ? children : <Navigate to ="/404" />

);


}

export default PrivateRoutes
```

Comment: Im new to react can you be more open and clear, what does that loader component contain ?

Comment: No worries, it does not really matter what is in the loader, it can just be `<p>Loading...</p>` as well.

Comment: oki and what is inside the isLoading variable how and where do i declare it, and same goes for the Loader where do i declare that function?

Comment: you touched the problem here and i got what you mean but i can't convert your speech into code can you just manipulate that code and make it correct then send it in answer please and sorry

Comment: Sure, I've added the code to my answer

Comment: Thank you sooo much, altho i don't understand how to logic worked there but at least it solved my problem i will read it and read it until i get it what really happend there